# PHP, since upgrading to 5.2.17 getting some warnings?

Tags: php, mysql

I can't reproduce this on my test server no idea why this is happening, other queries / functions work..

I'm getting this warning

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>
function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 
'--my isps server--' (10060) in D:\domains\mydomain.com\wwwroot\p
hp\_stdfuncs.php on line 191
```

This function and others like it are having problems (but some are ok), this is my include file...

```
function AddPageError($PageHandle, $Requested) {

global $server;
global $db;
global $user;
global $pass;
global $sDebug;

$con = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
```

I have an include file which sets those variables, as I say they work on other pages and functions..

No idea why ??

EDIT - phpMyAdmin warning

```
Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server 
version 5.1.42. This may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

Comment: Have you actually checked what the value of `$server` is?

Comment: It works intermittently... the only thing that I can see ... is  `Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server version 5.1.42. This may cause unpredictable behavior.`

Comment: can you include example of the function that is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL driver isn't enabled by default on 5.0->5.2, so most likely your new install didn't compile a new version for the 5.2 install, and is falling back to using the old 5.0 version.

Details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.installation.php) in the PHP docs